# mno-unaligned-access and -munaligned-access

Tags: c

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char test[64];
    memset(test,0, sizeof(test));
    int loop = 0;

    for (loop = 0; loop < sizeof(test); loop++)
    {
        test[loop] = loop;
        
    }
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n", *((int *)(test + 1)), *((int *)(test+2)), *((int *)(test+3)),*((int *)(test + 4)));
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, if I compile it with flags:

```
-g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Waddress -Warray-bounds -Wdiv-by-zero -Wfloat-equal -Wno-unused-function -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-float-equal -Wno-sign-compare -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ftree-vectorize -finline-functions -finline-limit=64 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -ffunction-sections -fPIE -pie -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -munaligned-access"
```

I think a bus error will occur, but it executes well.

I have tried compile it with:

```
-g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Waddress -Warray-bounds -Wdiv-by-zero -Wfloat-equal -Wno-unused-function -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-float-equal -Wno-sign-compare -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ftree-vectorize   -finline-functions -finline-limit=64  -fstack-protector-strong  -funwind-tables -ffunction-sections -fPIE -pie -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mno-unaligned-access"
```

but this also executes well.

Can anyone help me? Why "-munaligned-access" can't work?

Comment: what my think is if compile it with "-munaligned-access", after execute, the bus error will be raised, but actually execute well

Comment: This is not a C question, but a question about the memory architecture of your CPU. There's a lot of theory to be had on this, but realistically you'll be running on cached virtual memory on either Intel or ARM chips, where unaligned memory accesses are allowed.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What CPU architecture are you compiling for?

Comment: Note well that compilation options notwithstanding, your code exhibits strict-aliasing violations, and hence its behavior is undefined.  Including on machines that allow unaligned access of `int`s.  But that does not mean the program must fail, however, or if it does fail, that it must do so in some particular way that you expect.

Comment: x86 (except for sse instructions) generally has no problem with unaligned access. It just slows things down.